Why is "ref to data" allowed as a type for return parameters of functional methods?
The ABAP documentation states:

METHODS - RETURNING
[...]
Addition
... RETURNING VALUE(r) typing
Effect
Alongside any other formal parameters, a functional method has
precisely one return value r declared using the addition RETURNING.
The return value must be passed by value using VALUE and be fully
typed using typing.

but also:

Typings with TYPE REF TO data or TYPE REF TO object are also considered as full typings.

Why is it both:

Forbidden to declare a generic type for return parameters, and ...
Allowed to declare them as ref to data, which is the most generic type ?


It's as designed by SAP, so ask them. But having a complete type has the big advantage to allow the great inline declaration DATA(var) = function( ... ). References were natively designed to permit a full typing because they had to be casted to an exact type at runtime before they could be used. Also they are always 8 bytes long.

I‘m pretty sure there is a factual answer. REF TO is fixed size, whereas generic type needs an unknown size of bytes. As return values can be used in expressions, they must be stack allocatable
